# How to generate random number and use It few times?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, random, actionscript

So I need to generate random number and use It few times, problem is that It generating on EnterFrame function.

This function generate number 0-5:

```
function pn():Number {
    var pn:Number = Math.round(Math.random()*5);
    return pn;
}
```

Here I check if character not jumping and stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, jump);

```
    if(!mainJumping){
        mainJumping = true;
        stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, jump)
    }
```

And here is jump function where I need to use random generated number:

```
    function jump(e) { 
        if ( i < 50) {
            i++;
            item[1][pn()].y -=1     
        } else  {
            item[1][pn()].y += 1;
            if (item[1][pn()].y == 0){
                stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, jump)
            }
}
```

Problem is that in jump function every time IF is checked It generates new number. I need to make that number will be generated and not changed till this part:

```
if (item[1][pn()].y == 0){
     stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, jump)
}
```

After this It can generate new number. Have you ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Create an instance variable called myRandomNumber. In the getter for it, if it is null, call pn() to populate it.

Something like this:

In your class, define the variable:

```
private var _myRandomNumber:int = 0;
```

And in your getter:

```
public function get myRandomNumber():int {
    if (_myRandomNumber == 0) {
        _myRandomNumber = pn();
    }

    return _myRandomNumber;
}
```

Now, when you call myRandomNumber, you'll get a "random number" :)

Comment: Thank you for answer, but I misunderstood how to do that. Could you give me an example, please? Thank you again!

Comment: I misunderstood how It generate random number? It always will return 0, or no?

Comment: You initialize myRandomNumber at 0. Then, in your getter, if its still at 0, you populate it via _myRandomNumber = pn();

Comment: @StanislovasKalašnikovas does it make sense?

Answer (score 0):

```
// Create a variable higher up the scope chain to store the number 
var random = 0;

// Assuming this is in a function at the same level as the jump function
//function() ???? {
    if(!mainJumping){
        mainJumping = true;
        random = pn(); // Generate new random number when jump begins
        stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, jump)
    }
//}

function jump(e) { 
    var item = item[1][random]; // Grab the random item
    if ( i < 50) {
        i++;
        item.y -=1     
    } else  {
        item.y += 1;
        if (item.y == 0){
            stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, jump)
        }
    }
}
```